# launch gdb and print out variable value using ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, gdb, inspect

I want to write a ruby program that could inspect the variable value of a program by launch the `gdb` and then `print` that value. How could I achieve this?

If I were in the shell, I would do this :

```
  shell > gdb test
  [...gbd started]
  (gdb) p variable
  $1 = 20
  (gdb)
```

I also like to hear other ways that can achieve the same goal, not necessaliy to use gdb.

Comment: Did my answer help? Any followup questions I can help answer? Did open4 give you what you needed?

Comment: Sam, open4 is helpful but I have not been successful in using it to solve my problem. I will accept you answer if there will be no other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [open4](http://www.codeforpeople.com/lib/ruby/open4/), which allows you to open stdin, stdout, stderr to an arbitrary command. You could use open4 to run gdb exactly as you describe, I have done this personally and it works quite nicely. Might want to create a wrapper class that handles running commands and returning status, as open4 just gives you file handles.